# Reduce the size of windows in Ubuntu (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, window-manager

Sorry to bother you with a question probably very stupid, but I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity, and for some reasons, the windows seems to have a "minimal size". This is extremely annoying when I want to have 2 windows aside and when their minimum width don't match.

For instance, I can't reduce my gedit window below 400px width. Is it just me ? Is there a way to do that ? I couldn't find anything in the CompizConfig Setting Manager, and nothing on the internet seems to match my problem...

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT :** Actually, I'm trying to make a video of a window of my computer. I would like to have the targeted window take 80% of the screen, and use the space remaining to have notes. But the minimal size of gedit prevent me to do so...
As I found no solution to manage correctly these windows, I'm now looking for a new text editor that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: as a word of caution, please avoid CCSM as much as humanely possible. :)

Comment: This can help you! `http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=970478`

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunately, it doesn't work : even if I specify a size below 400 for my gedit windows, the window's width stay at 400. Actually, I don't have the problem with all the windows. It seems that each program can specify the minimum size of their window, but I would like to override that constraint if possible...

Answer (score 1):

There is a key combination of ctrl+alt+[NumpadNumber] which positions the window you have currently a focused on the screen.

- 1/3: left/right bottom quarter
- 7/9: left/right top quarter
- 4/6: left/right half
- 8/2: top/bottom half
- 5: whole screen/maximise

In your case, you would want to focus on one window, press ctrl+alt+4 then focus on another window and press ctrl+alt+6. Now they should be side by side on your screen.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I didn't know about these key combination. Actually you can have the same result by moving your window on the side of the screen. Unfortunately it doesn't solve exactly the problem. I should give more precision. See my edit.